# How to restart the IIS application pool remotely via command line and MSDeploy

Tags: remote-access, iis-10, msdeploy

I am creating GitHub actions to automatically deploy my website.

I have everything working other than the ability to **remotely** restart the application pool.

From what I've read, I need to stop the application pool, publish the site, start the application pool

```
shell: cmd
  run: '"C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",recycleMode="StopAppPool",computerName="${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",username="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }}",password="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}",AuthType="Basic"'
```

The output from this command is

> Info: Using ID '0a153730-a072-4bb1-868e-ae39a3e7659b' for connections to the remote server.
> Info: Adding MSDeploy.recycleApp (MSDeploy.recycleApp).
> Info: Adding recycleApp (***).
> Error: (11/23/2020 7:08:08 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
> Error: Unable to perform the operation. Please contact your server administrator to check authorization and delegation settings.

I don't know how to work out why this is the case! `MSDeploy.exe` works fine to deploy the website using the same remote path, username and password.

Do I need to enable remote recycling of application pools on the remote machine? I found the folder where the logs are stored but found nothing useful (although I likely don't know what I am looking for)

I don't know how to make this work. as the output is not telling me what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this using PowerShell.  The `WebAdministration` module has many cmdlets for managing IIS.  The snippet below will stop and start the `Example Pool` using the `Stop-WebAppPool` and `Start-WebAppPool`.  There is also a `Restart-WebAppPool` module you could run instead.

```
shell: powershell
run: Import-Module WebAdministration; Stop-WebAppPool -Name "Example Pool"

...your other deployment steps...

shell: powershell
run Import-Module WebAdministration; Start-WebAppPool -Name "Example Pool"
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this will work remotely - the reason I ask is you're not actually specifying a remote location, let alone any credentials in the example code you've given :(  - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps appears as if it's not possible (although I could have easily missed the information in that massive page)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the remote aspect.  Assuming WinRM is configured in your environment and the user running the command has the necessary access you can wrap the above commands in `Invoke-Command -Computername <your server> -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Stop-WebAppPool -Name "Example Pool"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, recreating the permissions on the server was all that was needed.

I may have changed the account from a standard to an administrator, I can't remember what the original type was!!

I also changed the password (although I'm confident that the password was not the cause)